# How do I replace an item in an array with one that isn't in said array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, object, replace

So I want to have one of the images in the array change to a question mark. Here's what I have so far.

```
var icons = new Array ();

    icons [0] = {   html: "Animals/Ape.png" };
    icons [1] = {   html: "Animals/Bat.png" };
    icons [2] = {   html: "Animals/Cow.png" };
    icons [3] = {   html: "Animals/Emu.png" };
    icons [4] = {   html: "Animals/Pig.png" };
    icons [5] = {   html: "Animals/Dog.png" };
    icons [6] = {   html: "Animals/Rat.png" };
    icons [7] = {   html: "Animals/Yak.png" };
    icons [8] = {   html: "Animals/Cat.png" };

function showBack()
    {
    document.getElementById('table').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tableblank').style.display = "block";
    icons[0]="Animals/Q.png";

    setTimeout(showFront,3000);
    }

function showFront()
    {
    document.getElementById('table').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('tableblank').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('speech').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('typewindow').style.display = "block";

    }
```

I've tried a couple of solutions but I haven't been able to make any work. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: First, you're defining the icons as objects (`={ html: something }` -- note the curly braces), and then assigning later as a string (`="Animals/Q.png"`). If the 'html' key/value is important, you'll need to change that. Second, where is the code that assigns an item from the array to an element?

Comment: <div id="containerGameplay">
<div id = "table">
 <script>
 
 for (i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
  {
  document.write ("<div class = 'tile'><img src='" + icons[i].html+ "'></div>");   
  }

 </script>
</div>

This what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to re-assign this object you may do it like that :

```
icons[0].html = "Animals/Q.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this...

```
var icons = [ "Animals/Ape.png", 
              "Animals/Bat.png",
              "Animals/Cow.png" ];

icons[1] = "Animals/Q.png";
document.write(icons[1]);
```

or if you want to keep an the url as an object...

```
var oIcons = [{ html:"Animals/Ape.png" }, 
              {html:"Animals/Bat.png"}, 
              {html:"Animals/Cow.png"}];

oIcons[2].html = "Animals/Q.png";
document.write(oIcons[2].html);
```

So basicly on show back you should have...

```
 icons[0].html="Animals/Q.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the code you posted in your comment:

```
<div id="containerGameplay">
    <div id = "table">
        <script>
            for (i = 0; i < 9 ; i++) {
                document.write ("<div class = 'tile'><img src='" + icons[i].html+ "'></div>");
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

You are running inline code on your page, which is executed as soon as the browser loads it. To change an image later, you'll need to create a reference to the element you want to change. The easiest way to do this is to give your elements IDs, which would change your code like so:

```
document.write("<div class='title'><img id='icon_" + i + "' src='" + icons[i].html+ "'></div>");
```

This will result in the first image (`icon[0]`) being applied to the element with the ID "icon_0", and so on for each image.

Later, when you want to change an image, you can get a reference to the correct element, and then change the `src` to that element:

```
elem = document.getElementById('icon_0');
elem.src = "Animals/Q.png";
```

Or, following what I believe you were trying to do originally, you can change the array, then set the new source (src):

```
icons[0].html = "Animals/Q.png";
document.getElementById('icon_0').src = icons[0].html;
```

They're both the same, but the second example is also storing the value in your array. Keep in mind that there is no automatic data-binding, so simply changing the array does not automatically update the image element.